# Redirect if something follows a directory, but not the directory itself

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

I'd like to redirect what follows a URI, but I keep running into trouble.

Basically, I'd like `/from/here/1234` redirected to `/to/there.php?id=1234`. But I can only get it to work if the URI is formatted with something *after* my pattern, such as `/form/here/1234/edit`.

This is the "working" rule:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_URI}" !-d
RewriteRule ^from/here/(.*)/edit/?$ /to/there.php?id=$1
```

I have tried it with and without the `RewriteCond`, with the following alterations:

- If I remove `/edit`, so that the rule is

  ```
  RewriteRule ^from/here/(.*)/?$ /to/there.php?id=$1`
  ```

  I get an "Internal Server Error", and "Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."

  I cannot access `/from/here` or `/from/here/` with this rule.
- If I add a leading slash, remove `/edit` and `?`, so that the rule is

  ```
  RewriteRule ^/from/here/(.*)/$ /to/there.php?id=$1
  ```

  I can access `/from/here` and `/from/here/` with this rule, but not `/from/here/1234` (404).

  I created a test 404 page just to print the `$_SERVER` variable, and nothing looks strange with the `REQUEST_URI` (i.e. showing as `/from/here/1234`).
- If I remove `/edit` and `?`, so that the rule is

  ```
  RewriteRule ^from/here/(.*)/$ /to/there.php?id=$1
  ```

  It works only if there is a trailing slash, unless I add the rule

  ```
  RewriteRule ^from/here/([a-z0-9\-]+)$ /from/here/$1/ [NC]
  ```

  While this works, it just doesn't feel *right*...

I have to be missing something simple/fundamental here, because I have struggled to find anything helpful on my own (which almost always means I've boneheadedly missed something "palm-face"/"head-wall"-worthy). I'm not exceedingly familiar with editing the .htaccess file, so that hasn't helped matters.

**TL;DR** - I would like to redirect what follows a slash, but only if there is in fact something that follows it. Forward `/from/here/1234`, but not `/from/here` or `/from/here/`.

Answer (score 0):

I knew it... the regex was too inclusive. Changed the rule to

```
RewriteRule ^from/here/([a-z0-9\-]+)/?$ /to/here.php?id=$1 [NC]
```

And all is well.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest modification is to change `.*` to `.+` so that there must be something, anything following `/from/here/`.

```
RewriteRule ^/from/here/(.+)$ /to/there.php?id=$1
```

If you don't want a trailing slash to be included in `$1` then you can make `.+` non-greedy by appending a question mark. Making it non-greedy will ensure that `/?` captures any trailing slash rather than `.+` doing so.

```
RewriteRule ^/from/here/(.+?)/?$ /to/there.php?id=$1
```